# ElasticSearch 1.6 seems to lose documents during high availability test

Tags: elasticsearch, high-availability

As part of an investigation for using ElasticSearch as a reliable document store, from a Java application, I'm running a basic HA test as follows:

I set up a minimal cluster using a readily available Docker image of ElasticSearch 1.6 (https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch), with:

- 2 master/data nodes
- 1 client node (as to always have someone to connect to)

Then I run a small loader app that inserts 500,000 documents of ~1KB each.

This takes approximately 1 minute and a half on my machine. During this time, I restart the current master node (docker restart).

At the end of the run, the Java API has responded OK to 100% of my queries, but when I check the documents count with a curl request, a few documents are missing (somewhere between 2 and 10 depending on runs I made)

Even with an explicit "_refresh" request on the index, my document count is the same.

My main concern of course is not that some documents cannot be stored during a crash but rather the positive result returned by the API (especially since I'm testing with WriteConsistencyLevel.ALL).

I'm aware of this ticket, yet unsure if it applies to my basic scenario

- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7572

My inserts are done as follows:

```
client.prepareUpdate("test", "test", id)
      .setDoc(doc).setUpsert(doc)
      .setConsistencyLevel(WriteConsistencyLevel.ALL)
      .execute.get.isCreated == true
```

The rest of the code can be found here :
https://github.com/joune/nosql/blob/master/src/main/scala/ap.test.nosql/Loader.scala

Please advise if you think I'm doing something obviously wrong.

(I know some will reply that considering ElasticSearch as a reliable document store is plain wrong, but that's the goal of the study and not the kind of answer I expect)

---

**Update** Additional logs as requested by Andrei Stefan

```
> grep discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes elasticsearch.yml
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2

> curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings' -d '{"transient":{"logger._root":"DEBUG"}}'
{"acknowledged":true,"persistent":{},"transient":{"logger":{"_root":"DEBUG"}}}%
> curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings' -d '{"transient": {"logger.index.translog":"TRACE"}}'
{"acknowledged":true,"persistent":{},"transient":{"logger":{"index":{"translog":"TRACE"}}}}%
```

Run test with 200,000 entries:

```
0 KO | 200000 OK
> curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/test/_count?preference=_primary'
{"count":199991,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0}}%
```

I've put the logs here: https://gist.github.com/ab1ed844f2038c30e63b

Comment: How many shards? How many replicas? What command are you using to check the documents count?

Comment: curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9202/test/test/_count'
{"count":499957,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0}}%

Comment: 2 out of 3 are data nodes and I request WriteConsistencyLevel.ALL so I'm guessing I have one replica

Comment: Have you set `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2`?

Comment: What results do you get if you run `curl -XGET 'localhost:9202/test/test/_count?preference=_primary"` ?

Comment: curl -XGET 'localhost:9202/test/test/_count?preference=_primary'
{"count":499957,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0}}%

Comment: And +1 to what @pickypg asked.

Comment: Indeed I haven't, my primary goal was to check "out of the box behaviour" but let me try this just now.

Comment: doesn't seem to help.. I ran the test twice with only 200K documents: first time I had 4 KOs (isCreated == false) but only 2 missing documents, second time 100% OK but 63 missing docs!

Comment: Can you tell which documents are missing? Are they all documents sent at the end? If all writes are acknowledged, then I really don't expect loss, especially with full write consistency unless there is split brain in the environment, which the shutdown should prevent anyway.

Comment: I store docs with an incremental counter ID and do the restart manually, last time after some 60K+ documents were stored. Gaps seem to appear around this index; like 64988 is found but most 64989 to 65000 are missing.

Comment: Can you provide the log files from both nodes after you perform another test? Make sure you have `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2` and you restarted the cluster after this change. Before the test starts, enable debug logging globally: `PUT /_cluster/settings
{"transient":{"logger._root":"DEBUG"}}` and TRACE logging for translog: `PUT /_cluster/settings
{"transient": {"logger.index.translog":"TRACE"}}`.

Comment: I've updated the question. Logs are here gist.github.com/ab1ed844f2038c30e63b

Comment: @apanday Based on the logs, it looks like one node is being shutdown before all of the writes are complete. With a write consistency level of `ALL`, it would prevent those documents from being saved to the primary as well. Can you verify that you're waiting for all index operations to complete (respond) before shutting down?

Comment: @pickypg that's exactly the point of the test; to simulate a crash (or maintenance restart) independently of the running application. I do expect some window of unavailability with this test, but the API tells me everything went fine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm aware of this ticket, yet unsure if it applies to my basic scenario
>   https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7572

I did some digging and I turn out it does. The reason is that during node shutdown we close the transport layer before we shut down the indices service, which means that ongoing operation are effectively partitioned away (exactly like the case of a networking issue). Obviously this is no good and I opened https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12314 to track this.

As a side note - with Elasticsearch 2.0, we have added a [shard header](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/7994) to the response, indicating how many shards were successful. This gives you a way to check wether an operation was indeed successfully written to all shards and retry if needed. This is an example of a successful response (writing to both primary and replica).

```
{
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 2,
        "failed" : 0,
        "successful" : 2
    },
```

Finally note that a shard failure doesn't mean that #7572 has played a part. It's highly unlikely.However, in all cases where #7572 did happen, the header will have total != successful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and raising the issue on ES. So with 2.0, I should be able to check that getResponse.getTotal() == getResponse.getSuccessful() ? The ticket also mentions that "For async writes it also includes the number of shards a write is still pending".. so I guess the equality doesn't always apply? Also, is there visibility on when 2.0 may be available?

Comment: yeah, but do not that an inequality almost always doesn't mean that anything is wrong, it's just the best litmus test right now.  Also async replication was removed in 2.0 after the feature was added. Last - all I can say is that we all want 2.0 to be out there as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 5):

Lots of good notes in the comments here. I would humbly suggest that a cluster with only two eligible master nodes is not "high availability." The elasticsearch [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/modules-discovery-zen.html) state:

> It is recommended to avoid having only two master eligible nodes, since a quorum of two is two. Therefore, a loss of either master node will result in an inoperable cluster.

Essentially, in a two-master cluster with `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` [properly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_important_configuration_changes.html#_minimum_master_nodes) set to 2, as soon as either node goes down, you can't have a master, and so you *no longer have a cluster*. If `minimum_master_nodes` was set to 1, you'd have a whole different set of problems to contend with ([split-brain](http://blog.trifork.com/2013/10/24/how-to-avoid-the-split-brain-problem-in-elasticsearch/)).  We run 3 masters for every ES cluster (and, furthermore, run dedicated masters) -- I would be very curious to know if you get different results with a 3 master cluster.

That said, it still seems quite incorrect that the API acknowledges receipt of your docs and then fails to persist them, but I think ultimately it probably does come back around to the fact that elasticsearch isn't designed to run a production-class implementation with only two master-eligible nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I perfectly understand the weakness of having only two nodes in prod, my concern is specifically on the wrong response returned by the API: I expect a failure. I don't know what will actually run or crash in prod, I just want my application to be aware that the document could not be saved so I can return an error or retry later.